# Mockito doReturn().when() calls original method

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, junit, mockito

I can't get Mockito to override a method in the class I am testing.

```
@Test
public void test_classToTest() throws Exception {
    DependencyA dependencyA = mock(DependencyA.class);
    DependencyB dependencyB = mock(DependencyB.class);
    DependencyC dependencyC = mock(DependencyC.class);

    ClassToTest classToTest = ClassToTest.builder().dependencyA(dependencyA)
            .dependencyB(dependencyB).dependencyC(dependencyC).build();

    classToTest= Mockito.spy(classToTest);

    Mockito.doReturn("This is not the method you are looking for").when(classToTest).storeContent(null, null, null);

    String result = classToTest.copyContent(someVariable, SOME_CONSTANT);
```

The method I am trying to override is classToTest.storeContent() which is called from inside classToTest.copyContent(). I am aware that this class is a little smelly, but I am not in a position to refactor it. However, this is not a very complicated setup and I am not sure why the actual .storeContent() method is getting called.

Comment: What is the method signature of the method you're testing?

Comment: What are the parameter values passed to the real method?  Perhaps replace the `null`s with `any()`s?

Comment: To Christopher's point above, please first check that `storeContent` is `public`, non-`static`, and non-`final`, and that ClassToTest is similarly `public` and non-`final`. (In general I'd also recommend against using `spy` on the class you're testing, and instead testing the class as a unit rather than teasing out the methods in isolation; I understand the appeal but for most classes it assumes some private details about the class's implementation that shouldn't be important to the test.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using the `null` parameters to setup the mocked `storeContent` method I would suggest using [`ArgumentMatchers.any`](http://site.mockito.org/javadoc/current/org/mockito/ArgumentMatchers.html#any())

E.g.

```
import static org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.*;

// ...

Mockito.doReturn("This is not the method you are looking for").when(classToTest).storeContent(any(), any(), any());
```

Comment: That was it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is a limitation in Mockito (and other mocking tools), that `final` methods cannot be stubbed.

Maybe your `ClassToTest#storeContent` is marked as `final` ?

If this is the case, just remove the `final` keyword, and the stubbing mechanism should kick-in.